# How can I get my old bootloader back?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I installed something and now I have bootloader from Debian.

[image]

It's not my screenshot!!

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

->Ubuntu 12.04
->Ubuntu 12.04 (recovery)
->Previous versions...
->Something with memory
->Something with memory
->Windows 7

When I chose Ubuntu, it will freeze and I have to restart the computer. 
So I have to wait 2 seconds, go down to windows and then up to ubuntu and press enter. That's working ... but it's .... not good....

So, please how can I uninstall this version to get the standart grub loader?

Or this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To install Grub Customizer, enter the following into the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then to run it,

```
grub-customizer
```

Hope this helps

## Update

To download Grub2

```
sudo apt-get install grub2
```